# I cannot create a table on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

I was trying to create the following table on PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
    movie_name VARCHAR(200),
    movie_year INTEGER,         
    country VARCHAR(100),
    genre VARCHAR
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_name, movie_year) 
);
```

But received the following error message:

```
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «(»
LINE 7:  PRIMARY KEY 
                 ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 166
```

Sorry, my PostgreSQL is in Spanish for some reason, but it basically says that there is a syntax error near the '('.

I´m following a course and the teacher was able to create this table on PostgreSQL without any problems, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a `,` after `genre VARCHAR`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan well, it is an SQL statement... But I'm not particularly opposed to removing it. Be my guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the last column definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies
(
    movie_name VARCHAR(200),
    movie_year INTEGER,         
    country VARCHAR(100),
    genre VARCHAR,
    -- Here -----^
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_name, movie_year) 
);
```